# node: global variable inside the try-catch with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
try {
  globalThis.addResult;
  await game
    .collection("game")
    .findOne({ activity_id }, async (err, result) => {
      addResult = result;
    });
  console.log(`this - ${addResult}`);
  return { sucess: true, addResult };
```

> ReferenceError: addResult is not defined

How can I set the variable and overwrite the value inside the mongoose query in order to return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a bad mix of async and callbacks in your code there. Mongoose provides a promise-based API that works with `await`, so you can simply use that:

```js
const addResult = await game
    .collection("game")
    .findOne({ activity_id })
    .exec();

console.log(addResult);

return { sucess: true, addResult };
```

Comment: Oh, just one minor question. What if there is an error? If I put that into `try-catch`, then I don't need to do like call back for error handling? thanks buddy

Comment: @GIHYUNNAM Yes, if you put this code in a try-catch, the `catch` should receive any error that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare a variable using let above await and then use it in the findone callback

```
let addResult;
await game
  .collection("game")
  .findOne({ activity_id }, async (err, result) => {
    addResult = result;
  });
console.log(`this - ${addResult}`);
return { success: true, addResult };
```

A more cleaner approach would be to assign the return value from await to `addResult` then use the values

```
const addResult = await game
  .collection("game")
  .findOne({ activity_id }, async (err, result) => {
    return result;
  });
console.log(`this - ${addResult}`);
return { success: true, addResult };
```

You should explore a little more about variable scoping in javascript. There are a lot of resource available for example this [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)